# Player moving when clicking buttons in menu

Tags: android, user-interface, button, unity-game-engine, onclick

My game is one scene so i got this little click to play menu setup. But the problem is when i click one of the buttons in the menu, the button gets pressed but the player starts moving also. What I am trying to achieve is if i click the menu buttons player wont move but as soon as i click somewhere else on the screen he will start moving.

My player controller script setup:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        inGameMenu.SetActive(true);
        startMenu.SetActive(false);

        if(grounded)
        {
            myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(angleOfJump, jumpForce);
        } 
    }

    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if(jumpTimeCounter > 0)
        {
            myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(angleOfJump, jumpForce);
            jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        jumpTimeCounter = 0;
    }
```

I know there has to be a simple solution but i just cant find it.

Comment: is the menu unity ugui?

Comment: The simplest way is to have a transparent button that fills the screen. However you should check the actual answers down below because they provide better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use state machine, and handle clicks based on your current

```
enum GameStates
{
    Started,
    Playing,
    Ended
};

GameStates currentState = GameStates.Started;


void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if(currentState == GameStates.Started)
        {
            inGameMenu.SetActive(true);
            startMenu.SetActive(false);
            currentState = GameStates.Playing;
        }
        else if(currentState == GameStates.Playing)
        {
            // handle gameplay click here.
        }
        // ... etc
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand that is not quite what OP wants. I think he wants that the player only doesn't move when the buttons arent pressed.

Comment: **AND** he wants that player doesn't move when click happens on one of menu objects. So let the OP have a say about it please. Good Day :)

Comment: @IanH. can you please explain why did you downvote my answer?

Comment: I did, as far as i comprehend the situation, your answer doesnt fully meet the request.

Comment: Well , This is not about whether you like it or not, because this is not your question at first place. And the answer **DOES** meet the request, its your problem if you can't interpret the question properly. Anyway even if the answer doesn't solve OP's problem, **HE** has right to not accept the answer but if you are downvoting it (being a third person) based on what you [**think or understand**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120780/player-moving-when-clicking-buttons-in-menu/39121015?noredirect=1#comment65591401_39121015), its not quite good behaviour.

Comment: Umair thank you for your answer, i tried to implement States in my code and it sovled the problem. Now im trying to master the UI so it would look like menu in the game Zig Zag, when u click on buttons UI panel pops up but if you click elsewhere the game starts.

Comment: @Richarrd82 I am pleased to help. I would suggest you to create a full screen button, set it transparent and place it on top in menu hierarchy so if nothing else is under click, this button will be clicked to start the game. Please upvote & mark my answer correct :)

Comment: @Richarrd82 Since this fixed your problem, why not accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state machine as suggested by Umair M. This is the best solution for handle easily a pause menu or something like that (for example). But another simple solution is create a bool inizialized to false, and at the botton pression set this bool to true for allow the character movement.

An example:

In the player script:

```
bool CharacterActive = false;

void Update()
{
    if(CharacterActive) // if the bool variable is active..
    {
        if(Input.MouseStuff :D) // if movement key pressed..
        {
            // ..Move the character
        }
    }
}

public void OnButtonClick()
{
    CharacterActive = true;
}
```

In Unity editor add to the button the OnButtonClick() method from the player gameobject in OnClick() component. Here you can see a video about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYzdhiRiKd0

Comment: Thanks tried it but still doesnt work the way i would like it to. Im trying to achieve that touch to play menu like in the game Zig Zag:)

Comment: You can create a time variable (timePassed = Time.deltatime) to handle the time between the pression and the beginning of movement, another tools that can help you are the trigger: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NBYqPAA5Es . Hope that this can help you :)